# java.awt Shape not rotating properly

Tags: java

I'm creating a Pool game in Java, where the cue is being rotated according to where the mouse is on the screen, however the rotation is always +- 20 degrees off

Since the cue is only in visual form, i'll provide the rendering code :

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) graphics;

    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    super.paintComponent(g);
    //draw here
    g.drawImage(Resources.getPoolTableImage(), 0, 0, null);

    double dx = EventHandler.getMouseX() - table.getWhiteBall().getPosition().x;
    double dy = EventHandler.getMouseY() - table.getWhiteBall().getPosition().y;
    double dir = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

    System.out.println(Math.toDegrees(dir));

    g.fill(Resources.rotate(new Rectangle((int) table.getWhiteBall().getPosition().x + 3,
            (int) table.getWhiteBall().getPosition().y + 10, 20, 100), dir));
    for (Ball ball : table.getBalls()) {
        ball.render(g);
    }

    this.repaint();
}
```

And here is the method responsible for rotating the shape

```
public static Shape rotate(Rectangle rect, double angle) {
    Rectangle2D myRect = new Rectangle2D.Double(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(angle - 90, rect.x + rect.width / 2, rect.y);
    Shape rotatedShape = at.createTransformedShape(myRect);
    return rotatedShape;
}
```

The rotation instance is being created with -90 degrees in an attempt to fix the shape's rotation, but it's still off.

Comment: The units for these methods are radians, not degrees. This is described in the documentation.

Comment: @pvg Thank You ! I replaced angle - 90 with angle - Math.toRadians(90) and it works !